# Installing python setup.py into an alternative path doesn't find installed package

Tags: python, installation, importerror, setup.py

I have a test setup file, which I made for a simple "hello world" script. I have a package named `mytest` which has a function `hello`. Now, I have a very simple `setup.py`. Everything works fine, if I just run `python setup.py install`. But if I want to install lib into home folder (`python setup.py install --home=/home/blah`), the package is not available anymore (running `import mytest` in python gives me `ImportError: No module named mytest`).

Should I add pth-file manually into `site-packages` folder? I tried it (with contents `/home/blah/lib/python`, where my package is put) and importing `mytest` worked fine. Shouldn't it be done automatically? Or have I missed something?

EDIT:

output of install:

```
ago@dellbert:~/py/mytest-0.1$ python setup.py install --home=/home/ago/py/
running install
running build
running build_py
copying src/mytest/mytest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/mytest
running build_scripts
copying and adjusting src/main.py -> build/scripts-2.6
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/mytest/mytest.py -> /home/ago/py//lib/python/mytest
byte-compiling /home/ago/py//lib/python/mytest/mytest.py to mytest.pyc
running install_scripts
copying build/scripts-2.6/main.py -> /home/ago/py//bin
changing mode of /home/ago/py//bin/main.py to 755
running install_egg_info
Removing /home/ago/py//lib/python/mytest-0.1.egg-info
Writing /home/ago/py//lib/python/mytest-0.1.egg-info
```

and setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='mytest',
      description='test',
      author='Ago',
      author_email='email',
      version='0.1',
      package_dir={'mytest': 'src/mytest'},
      packages=['mytest'],
      scripts=['src/main.py']
      )
```

Folder structure:

```
-src:
   -mytest:
       __init__.py
       mytest.py
    main.py
setup.py
```

`main.py` is just an executable which imports mytest and calls function to print hello world. But I have tried to just run `import mytest` in python to see, whether lib is installed.

Comment: Well, currently I have added mytest.pth file into `site-packages` with contents `/home/ago/py/lib/python`. But will, if anyone has a solution why my module/package isn't available with `python setup.py install`, I'm still interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems python unified at least the parameters in Unix- and Windows environments. Looking at the python reference today (https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html, Dec. 2017), it shows that in both OS you can use the `--prefix=<head installation path>`. Have a look on the reference, section ["Alternate installation: Unix (the prefix scheme)"](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#alternate-installation-unix-the-prefix-scheme) and ["Alternate installation: Windows (the prefix scheme)"](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#alternate-installation-windows-the-prefix-scheme). I just tested it with Oct2Py (Octave-to-Python converter), which was a trouble to install with easy_install or pip, but did the job this way quite well.

Your python package will be then in (assuming you use Python 2.7) `<head installation path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages` or `<head installation path>/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
python setup.py install --prefix=<your path>
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this code will help, I didn't tested it.
If your path is `/src/lib/`:

```
python setup.py install --install-lib /src/lib/
python setup.py install --user --prefix=
```

or

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('your-path')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).